# Only half of the object is visible

Tags: rendering, visibility

I have the problem that I cannot see the liquid as soon as the cup is visible. How do i solve this?

[image: Liquid with cup]

[image: Liquid without cup]

Comment: Could you please share your file? https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: Sure, here it is: https://pasteall.org/blend/4b2154155807435591394dc6ba1cea9d

Comment: if you mean that the bottom of the liquid is cropped I guess you need to scale the cup a bit

Comment: Even if you look at it without the plane, it doesn't help. Of scaling the liquid doesn't appear either. And yes, the problem is that it's cropped when don't hide the cup in viewport.

Comment: see my answer, it looks like it has to do with overlapping faces, move your cup a bit and it will fix it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like it has to do with overlapping faces, here is what happens if you move up the liquid a bit (you can move the cup but the liquid is parented to the cup so it will move along):

[image]

[image]

Comment: I think I'm a little dumbfounded right now. How exactly did you move this?

Comment: what do you mean by how? Select the liquid and move it up (G + Z)

Comment: Ah, I got it! You told me to move the cup, but it worked with the liquid only. Thanks for explaining, the problem is solved. :)

Comment: yes actually the liquid is parented to the cup  ;)